# Alternatives to RabbitMQ for .NET centric shop?

Tags: .net, messaging, rabbitmq

I need a reliable messaging solution.  It looks like RabbitMQ would address the needs of my application.  However, my environment is not well suited to deploying Erlang and Mnesia on a server.  It is an enterprise environment and it is a huge battle of red tape to get "non-standard" pieces like that deployed.  I would prefer to find a reliable messaging framework similar to RabbitMQ, but built on .NET.  Storing messages in Oracle and/or SQL Server would be a bonus.  Anything like that out there?

I'm aware of NServiceBus, but I don't think this is focused on reliable messaging as much as RabbitMQ is.

Comment: `I'm aware of NServiceBus, but I don't think this is focused on reliable messaging as much as RabbitMQ is` What makes you say that?

Comment: Ehh...my own (quite possibly limited) understanding of NServiceBus.  If you'd like to correct me, go for it.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what NServiceBus is trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about good old msmq? It's standard component on windows server systems, has WCF bindings... so I guess this is exactly what you are looking for. Though, afaik it has its own filesystem-based message storage, and doesn't support sql server or oracle for that purpose.

Comment: MSMQ, from what I understand, is a mechanism for persisting messages, but it doesn't have any kind of service layer for orchestrating between message publishers and subscribers or anything like that.  I would prefer not to write all that myself.  But if I were, the persistence layer would quite possibly be MSMQ.

Comment: Which is why Microsoft created WCF.

Comment: I will have to research using WCF with MSMQ.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I would use NServiceBus (you already mentioned) or MassTransit - both use MSMQ.

Both are focussed on reliable messaging, and have been known to be used in many critical applications.

Answer (score 0):

There is also ActiveMQ. It's geared more for Java, but you can get it working in .NET, I have a large ActiveMQ deployment all using C#, but I do plan to convert it to RabbitMQ.

Comment: ActiveMQ is no longer being actively developed since the vendor has created ZeroMQ. For inhouse use, ZeroMQ is a great solution since no server needs to be installed. In fact, any functionality that you might want from a server, can be programmed in one of your applications using ZeroMQ, so you have the ultimate in flexibility and it is easy to build and to support.

Comment: @Michael Dillon  Thanks never heard of ZeroMQ before. I'll have to look into it.